# Is it possible to open colorbox from another colorbox without closing the parent?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

So yeah, like stated in title, i'm trying to open another colorbox from within a colorbox, without closing it. Is it possible?

I open the main one like this:

```
$("#popup").colorbox({fastIframe: false});
```

The `#popup` is link to another page (using yii framework, so it renders the view). Now inside that colorbox, i have another button, which is supposed to open another colorbox with some extra info. I tried to adding the `href` attribute to colorbox itself:

```
$("#extra").colorbox({width:"600px", overlayClose:true, href:"<?php echo "/game/extra/id/" . $question->id ?>"});
```

But i'm having no luck with that, new content is displayed in original colorbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to open colorbox from another colorbox without closing
>   the parent?

Short answer for the question that was in your title: No, it wouldn't be IF you did not rewrite the `colorbox` plugin on your own.

Quoted from Topher Fangio in [Multiple Jquery modal Dialog Boxes in one page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972316/multiple-jquery-modal-dialog-boxes-in-one-page)

> Many modal dialog boxes have the ability to insert data into the modal
>   dialog by use of an iFrame. I'm not sure which plugin you are using
>   (or the built-in jQuery ones I guess) but I'm fairly certain that it
>   allows you to have one modal dialog whose content changes based on
>   what was clicked.

If you didn't notice, out there has existed many same questions around it already

[How to have multiple jQuery colorboxes in the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510911/how-to-have-multiple-jquery-colorboxes-in-the-same-page)

Most of answers said NO. Here is quoted from Jack on [jQuery ColorBox real multiple instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724452/jquery-colorbox-real-multiple-instances)

> I don't think there is going to be a practical way to do this. You
>   would have to re-code a lot of the plugin for it to support multiple
>   instances.
>
> You may be able to keep your iframes as different pieces of inline
>   content. I'm not sure if moving an iframe around the DOM will cause it
>   to lose it's scrolltop position or not.

I would not consider this as such an answer, but just want to point you out the correct direction once you would like a jQuery plugin has ability to support multiple instance

You could find it here as beginning

[5. Multi-Show/Hide -- a. view (show all), b. view (hide all), c. view (show+hide some)](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/#examples)

Comment: I'm afraid it is too late to switch to another plugin as colorbox is heavily used in the project. But thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

What I did to workaround this limitation is using Colorbox and then open a ThickBox from there. I know it's really a dirty way of doing things but at least I'm partly getting the result that I was looking for. Otherwise you'll need to figure out a way of closing a Coloborx without loosing its content if it has a form in it then open a new colrbox and upon closing reopen the previous saved colorbox.